# vs code - Expected java package name error

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have a java project with the following directory structure (as required by Gradle's `'java'` plugin, assuming all defaults).

```
projectRootDir
 - src/main/java/com/myproj/Sample.java
 - build.gradle
```

And

```
// Sample.java code
package com.myproj;

public class Sample{
    ...
}
```

Opening `projectRootDir` folder in VS Code shows the following package naming error in Sample.java:

`The declared package "com.myproj" doesn't match the expected package "main.java.com.myproj"`

How to make VS Code recognise/use the package mentioned in the code?

**Note:** I am using the following extensions: **Language Support for Java(TM) by RedHat** and **Debugger for Java** by Microsoft.

Comment: you need to configure your VS code to take `src/main/java` as the source root folder instead of just `src`. That should do the trick

Answer (score 22):

If your files are already in the correct directory, press F1 and type in "Clean the Java Language Server Workspace"

Comment: The easiest way to fix it, i was getting crazy

Answer (score 6):

To get things right, add the root folder of you project in workspace. To do this in VS Code, go to File -> "Add folder to workspace" and then select the root folder (source folder).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, as workspaces aren't required. If you open the folder as a project you shouldn't need a workspace

Comment: @DiamondDrake Have you figured this out? I have a multi-module maven project and VSCode cannot render the sub modules to save its life. I have to open the project in its own VSCode window. This is insane because I have over 20+ sub modules in this project.

Comment: @user0000001 for me it was a parent pom that changed the src root

Comment: @DiamondDrake Thank you for taking the time to reply. Mine was simply clearing the `workspaceStorage` directory in the VSCode installation.

Comment: FWIW I also had to right click the main folder (just the blank space where top level files go) and choose "remove folder from the java source path"

Answer (score 6):

Because `vscode` set the `src folder` as the default `Java Source Path`, you should change it to folder `src/main/java`. Just right click the folder `src/main/java` in `vscode` and click the option `Add Folder to Java Source Path`, then reopen the file, and the error is gone.

Comment: Doesn't work with the plugin OP is using, throws a warning that says use the pom to configure src root

Comment: Does not work when I use Java Dependency Viewer extention.

Comment: This answer helped me amazingly, thanks! Just for anyone who bumps into this error (maybe when using the Java Project Manager extension): `Cannot add to source path because parent is already...` just right click on the previous root of your sources (e.g.: src folder) and remove it from source path, then add the new root to the source path. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 6):

Project Root --> .vscode --> settings.json

changed below entry to point to my root source folder. This was set to src/pkg1.  Changed to src and it started working.

{
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
"src"
]
}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was `faustinoaq.javac-linter` extension. I uninstall the linter extension and everything works.